# how to reform the data set based on one column that needs to be converted from decimal values to integers?

Tags: r, formatting

At one step of my analysis my data looks like this:

```
x<-c(-0.023,0.009, .1, 1.02, 1.9)
y<-c(0.5, 2, 2, 3, 4)
data<-cbind(x,y)
```

However, I want my data to work in this format:

```
x<-c(0,1)
y<-c(4, 7)
data<-cbind(x,y)
```

How do I reformat my table so that my x values are integers with aggregated y-values corresponding to that x-value?

Also, how do I select the table to start from 0 instead of negative values?

Comment: It's very unclear what you asking. How did you get from the first `data` to the second one?

Comment: @David Arenburg The second data is the format that I am looking for. I should have changed the variable name for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

First, you clean up the data (round `x` and remove any rows with negative `x`).  Then there are a number of ways to finish.  I'll give you two:

```
x <- c(-0.023,0.009, .1, 1.02, 1.9)
y <- c(0.5, 2, 2, 3, 4)

# Dataframes are sometimes easier to work with than matrices
data <- data.frame(x,y)

# Round x down to the nearest integer
data$x <- floor(data$x)

# Remove any negative x
data <- data[data$x>=0,]

# First aggregation method
data1 <- aggregate(data$y,by=list(data$x),sum)

# Second aggregation method
library(plyr)
data2 <- ddply(data,.(x),summarize,y=sum(y))
```